# How to copy folders+files as per the folder names passed as parameter in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an on-prem file storage, there I have a folder named 'India'. Inside 'India', there are 36 folders with all the state/union territory names. I want to build a copy data pipeline that takes a parameter for state names, and while copying it will exclude the folder names given in the parameter.

for example, if I give 'Kerala', it will exclude Kerala. If I give 'Kerala','Karnataka','Odisha' it will exclude them while copying.

I treid using a filter condition, but not sure how to use it properly. So need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use filter in the following way. First create an array parameter of the folder names that you don't need.

[image]

- Use `getmetadata activity` the list of folders. The following is the output of my get metadata activity with childitems:

[image]

- Now, use filter in the following way with dynamic content values similar to what is given below:

```
items: @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems
condition: @not(contains(pipeline().parameters.reject,item().name))
```

[image]

- This would give result as shown in the below final image.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer . Can you please let me know how to use foreach and the copy data so that the folerds and their files would get copied to the destination?. I am new to Azure, so facing some challenges.

Comment: Hey @PrasenjitPatnaik, if you don't have any issues regarding the above approach (your requirement as stated in the question), accept this solution as and raise a new question.